# Pushing a file with Pushbullet via Intent (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent

I've got an intent in my app to share log files, and I can successfully send the log as an attachment in email, or push to DropBox, and all is well. But when I select Pushbullet, it brings up the Pushbullet dialog, with an attachment, but that attachment seems to have no name, and I can't actually get it to send.
The code I'm using is:

```
final Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

String fileName = "log_" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".txt";

try {
        // Create a file in the app's cache folder
        createCachedFile(mContext, fileName, getLogText());
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("content://" + LogFileProvider.AUTHORITY + "/" + fileName));

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send Log"));
```

createCachedFile basically just copies the log file to a new file in /data/data/{package}/cache, and that works when I choose gmail or DropBox, but not PushBullet.
A related question is, how can I auto-populate text in the "Optional Message" field of the Pushbullet dialog?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createCachedFile will give you a File object. Using that file object you can try below.

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send Log"));
```

Below is the sample code (just for test) which I tried and it works,

```
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String fileName = "log_"
                    + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".txt";
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/" + fileName);
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                // We can write to file here.
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "SendFile"));
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I couldn't get your last solution to work either - but I was able to get it working by scrapping what I'd done, and using a FileProvider (using the Support Library).  It is explained here: https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html.

However, since I have no doubt your response is correct, and I was just missing something, I am going to mark your response as the answer to the question - hopefully your response or my solution will help someone else!